# Make Wordpress wp_delete_attachment delete files from a pre-defined custom folder

Tags: php, wordpress, delete-file

We have created a custom post type which allows our client to upload files to a folder outside of the standard Wordpress uploads folder (wp-content/upload-assets). These files are to be handled seperately from the standard wp-content/uploads folder and this is why we CANNOT use

```
define( 'UPLOADS', 'mycustomfolder' );
```

in the wp-config.php.

Instead we use this to temporarily change the uploads folder to wp-content/upload-assets:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$uploaded_file = wp_handle_upload($_FILES['xxxx_image'], $upload_overrides);
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
```

We are using this to remove all attachments from a particular post:

```
add_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
$attachments = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status'    => 'any',
            'post_parent'    => $pid
) );

foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
   if ( false === wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true ) ) {
      echo 'Attachment could not be deleted.';
   }
}
remove_filter('upload_dir', 'my_upload_dir');
```

wp_delete_attachment should also delete all associated files from disk but it doesn't work because our files are in our custom folder (wp-content/upload-assets).

Here's the code for our my_upload_dir function:

```
function my_upload_dir($upload) {
    $upload['subdir']   = '';
    $upload['basedir']  = WP_CONTENT_DIR;
    $upload['baseurl']  = WP_CONTENT_URL;
    $upload['path']     = $upload['basedir'] . '/upload-assets';
    $upload['url']      = $upload['baseurl'] . '/upload-assets';
    return $upload;
}
```

How do we make wp_delete_attachment remove the files in our custom wp-content/upload-assets folder?

Comment: First have a look at the attachments guid if they are indeed in the custom folder.

Comment: @Ervald - Yep. Definately in the custom folder!

Comment: Do you have the right permissions to that folder same as the default?

Comment: @Ervald - Yep. I can delete manually using unlink so permissions are ok.

Comment: Having this same issue... Did you manage to find a solution?

Answer (score 7):

Hi You can do this way if want to delete the file, but it will not remove all post meta fields, taxonomy, comments, etc. associated with the attachment.

Hope this help

```
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
  if ( false === wp_delete_attachment( $attachment->ID, true ) ) {
    $file = get_attached_file( $attachment->ID );
    $file = str_replace( "uploads", "upload-assets", $file);
     wp_delete_file( $file );
   }
 }
```

I have not tested this code, but i hope it should work

Answer (score 3):

Staying in the domain of current question you can use "get_attached_file" filter to directly alter the file path string used to grab the path of file to be deleted. Specifically add this function to your functions.php

```
function sr_update_uploads_directory( $file )
{
    return str_replace( "uploads", "upload-assets", $file) // Change path to upload-assets from uploads
}
add_filter( 'get_attached_file', 'sr_update_uploads_directory' );
```

Don't have time for testing currently. So, please excuse me for that. Hope it helps. :)